# blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

```
async onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token/login',{
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password,
    }).then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data));
        this.props.history.push('/protcted')
    });
console.log("resgister!");
// console.log(resd.json());
```

}

async componentDidMount() {

```
    if (!this.state.logged_in) {
        this.props.history.push('./login')
    }
  console.log(user));

    if (this.state.logged_in) {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/users/me', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
               Accept, Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
                "Authorization": `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "withCredentials": true,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                
            }
        })
            .then(res => JSON.stringify(res.data))
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({ username: json.username });
            });
    }


}
```

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'authapp',
'rest_framework',
'djoser',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'corsheaders',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbz1e.png)

signup complete working this localhost URL but login can not work.and in this onSubmit method completely work token does store in localStorage but I try to authenticate with this token I get this error.

And the surprise is I request http://localhost:8000/auth/users/me this URL in Postman then I get data

you can see in this that photo in the given link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa6AB.png)

Comment: You're confusing request and response headers. CORS headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` should be sent in the response, not the request.

Answer (score -1):

[The default list of allowed headers in `django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/3.4.0/README.rst#cors_allow_headers) does not include `access-control-allow-headers`.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Max-Age`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` are [HTTP headers that could be sent back for access control requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers).

The request should be without them. Also, [`credentials` option](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) should be configured as its own entry in `fetch` init options to permit cookies to be sent to other domains.

```
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'   
        },
        credentials: 'include'
```